# How to prevent obstruction of apache connection-slots

Tags: apache-2.2, clients

i have an apache 2.2 with

```
ServerLimit        50
MaxClients         50
```

now when i run jmeter wth 50 threads and keep alive checked, all slots belong to jmeter. And i can't access the page with my browser.

i aleady tried

```
MaxRequestsPerChild  1
```

but this didn't change any thing

is there any out-of-the-box solution in apache to prevent one client using all slots?

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve? This is essentially how Prefork works. Depending on the problem, there are different possibly solutions.

Comment: the problem is that someone can dos my server just by running jmeter with 50 threads. And no other client will getting any response

Comment: Have you tried using `mod-evasive`? It's specifically designed to detect DoS attacks and block their IP at the firewall level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see this specified, so try adding `KeepAliveTimeout 5` to your apache configuration. Also, why only 50 MaxClients? You must have a very tiny server for it to be set this low.

`MaxRequestsPerChild` doesn't do anything as any requests through a KeepAlive counts as a single request as far as Apache is concerned. In this configuration (prefork), you can leave out `ServerLimit` entirely.

Comment: if i set it to 150 i can set jmeter to 150 threads... thats no solution.. and KeepAliveTimeout won't work because jmeter runns infinite and does not time out

Comment: Why are you using `jmeter` to do this? Apachebench (`ab`) is a much better indication of real-world usage. However, you can take a look at [mod_evasive](http://www.zdziarski.com/blog/?page_id=442) and configure it to prevent client exhaustion.